# Preface requirements concerning acknowledgement

Tags: acknowledgement

I am curious to know what the preface requirements are for bachelor and master theses. Are you legally (or morally) required to use the full names of the people included in the acknowledgements?

Does anyone know?

Comment: I used the full names of people who provided help on my dissertation itself: the committee members and proofreaders.  I used first names only for supportive friends and family.  As far as I know, there is no legal requirement in the United States, and no moral requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acknowledgments part is the only place where you are completely free to write whatever you want. You are not legally or morally required to write anything *unless* you agreed to previously. Some funding entities, generally private companies may require you to do so (e.g. NVIDIA gives free GPUs to researchers with the condition they acknowledge NVIDIA in papers).

I've seen people in this site mentioning that they acknowledged God, a fictional dog and non-existent people. Just write what you want.

Comment: Thank you too for your feedback. Or, rather, your responses.

Comment: @Christopher However, note that is a good practice to acknowledge the people that actually helped you, such as your supervisor or colleagues. Don't burn bridges by not putting them there.

Comment: I did add the acknowledgements, I was just curious to the general requirements:)